# hide show menu getElementsByClassName

Tags: javascript, menu, getelementsbyclassname

I wanna make a hide/show menu in JavaScript. I must use getElementsByClassName in my menuHeader at least! I have fixed so I can hide and show only the first menuContent. I would like to click on one menuHeader so it opens the menuContent who is under the menuHeader! How can I do to hide and show the other content to(menuContent2) without making several functions? Is it possible? Can I fix this with a loop?

Here is my HTML code:

```
<a class="menuHeader">SPORT</a><br>
    <div class="menuContent">//**It only opens this Content no matter which menuHeader I click on!**
    <a href="">Result</a><br>
    <a href="">Live</a><br>
    <a href="">Standing</a><br>
    </div>

    <a class="menuHeader">NEWS</a><br>
    <div class="menuContent2">
    <a href="">Local</a><br>
    <a href="">World</a><br>
    </div>
```

Here is my JavaScript code:

```
    function menuFunction(){

    var ele = document.getElementsByClassName("menuContent")[0];

    for(var i = 0; i < ele.length; i++)
    {
    ele[i];
    }


    if(ele.style.display == "none") {
            ele.style.display = "block";

    }
    else {
        ele.style.display = "none";

    }


}

   function init(){

   var menu = document.getElementsByClassName("menuHeader");
    for(var i = 0; i < pic.length; i++) {
    {
        menu[i].onclick = menuFunction;
    }

   }

   } 

   window.onload = init;
```

//EDIT
I fixed it, thanks Arun P Johny.

Comment: "*I must use getElementsByClassName in my menuHeader at least*" - why? `getElementsByClassName()` isn't supported by Internet Explorer, whereas, for example, `document.querySelectorAll()` *is*.

Comment: Actually, it is supported in IE9+. Your problem is that you are getting the first `menuContent` element in the _document_, not within the clicked element.

Answer (score 4):

Because `var ele = document.getElementsByClassName("menuContent")[0];` will always return the first element with the class `menuContent`.

```js
var menu = [].slice.call(document.getElementsByClassName("menuHeader"), 0);
for (var i = 0; i < menu.length; i++) {
  menu[i].onclick = menuFunction;
}

var contents = document.getElementsByClassName("menuContent");

function menuFunction() {
  var ele = contents[menu.indexOf(this)];
  if (ele.style.display == "none") {
    ele.style.display = "block";
  } else {
    ele.style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

```html
<a class="menuHeader">SPORT</a><br/>
<div class="menuContent">
  <a href="">Result</a><br/>
  <a href="">Live</a><br/>
  <a href="">Standing</a><br/>
</div>

<a class="menuHeader">NEWS</a><br/>
<div class="menuContent">
  <a href="">Local</a><br/>
  <a href="">World</a><br/>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi, when I use your code I get the following error if I put the "var contents" and "var menu" in function init :
ReferenceError: contents is not defined

I wanna have "var menu" inside "function init"

If I put "var contents" outside "function init" I get this error:
ReferenceError: menu is not defined

What am I doing wrong??